# How can I know if Windows Update is currently running?

Tags: c#, windows-update

I am working on C# with .net 3.5

My application needs to put the computer to sleep. the problem is that if Windows Update is running it won't hold the computer from going to sleep. so I want to wait until windows update will finish before putting the computer to sleep.

Is there a way to programatically tell if windows update is currently running?

I tried to check if Wuauclt or TrustedInstaller are running, but apparently they are running even when windows update is not running.

Comment: do you mean to say its when Windows Update is being downloaded or installed?

Comment: I mean when windows update is doing something - could be searching, downloading or installing an update.